# Does Docker Swarm have IPVS (IP fail-over) available?

Tags: docker-swarm, percona-xtradb-cluster, proxysql

Recently we have been investigating running Percona cluster with ProxySQL on Docker Swarm, the following guide for reference:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/06/14/scaling-percona-xtradb-cluster-proxysql-docker-swarm/

Since ProxySQL is SQL load balancer in this Docker Stack, how could I set it up so that we could have active/passive ProxySQL containers running on two runners node with nearly instant fail-over, so all application will still using the same DB hostname / IP as target without changing anything?

(And please, I don't make the rule nor bends it, that's our business requirement to have IP HA available on Docker Swarm)